# Webpack Ajax response is undefined when debugging

Tags: javascript, webpack

When put a break point in console.log and try to see the response in data it says data is undefined.
If i place this JS file directly on the page and i try to see data it shows the response correctly.

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'json',
url: "/Agents/es",

success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}});
```

Is there a problem with my webpack settings?

I'm using VS 2017 and net core

```
module.exports = function (env) {

env = env || {};
var isProd = env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// Setup base config for all environments
var config = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "Features"),
    entry: {
        "Maps": [ "./Map/Scripts/map.js"],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css?$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: "ts-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    }
}
return config;
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, The problem was that i was not building in development mode.

"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --profile **--mode development**",

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "/Agents/es",

  success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  }});
```

Your `$.ajax()` is missing the data attribute.So you are basically posting/sending nothing.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/Agents/es",
    data: {
    //your data here
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The data is undefined. Which means you have not defined any data when posting.

Comment: It's a get operation not a post, i'm not getting the data when i put a breakpoint in the console.log(data) line. Also this only happens when its built in webpack, if done directly i do get a response.